# vsjitdebugger.exe - Attaching to remote processes

Tags: .net, visual-studio, remote-debugging

I'm looking into how I can programatically attach to a remote process (e.g. from powershell) - not a local one.

Using vsjitdebugger.exe -p  allows you to connect to a process on your local machine.

It doesn't provide any helpful extra arguments for attaching to a remote process (as you can in Visual studio by attach to process). There is however an undocumented "args" that can be passed in, but not sure if this will do the trick.

Any tricks / help in how to attach to a remote process from the commandline? Any debugger gurus know how Visual studio does the wrap-up when using tools-attach to?

Comment: Anything wrong with `vsjitdebugger.exe /?` ? The -p parameter takes a process id, which you can find quite easily.

Answer (score 0):

It's for local debugging. The [args] parameter was probably deemed obvious... It's supposed to mean arguments for the application you're debugging, not for the debugger.

I bet one could write an extension that exposes a command, which can be passed in to devenv.exe on startup.